# Is there possible to intercept method like this by using Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

This is my first post in here, Have a nice day everybody :)

I created an annotation named "Validate"

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Validate {
    Class<? extends MethodInterceptor>[] value();
}
```

Then decorate it before a method which need to be intercepted.

```
@Validate({OneInterceptor.class, TwoInterceptor.class})
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    //Do something
}


OneInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {.....}  TwoInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor{....}
```

Is there a possible to bind interceptors like this by using Guice ? I just want to Guice binds these interceptors in the Run-time dynamically. 
Thanks everybody!

Comment: Have you read this: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mlk noted, you can write a MethodInterceptor that does this, though there's no reason that the validators mentioned have to be MethodInterceptors as well--and, in fact, it will likely be easier that way because you don't have to worry about `proceed()`.

Please pardon me if this code doesn't compile, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
public interface RequestValidator {
  void validate(HttpServletRequest req) throws ValidationError;
}

public class ValidationModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Validate.class), 
        new ValidateInterceptor());
  }
}

public class ValidateInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Method method = invocation.getMethod();
    Validate validate = method.getAnnotation(Validate.class);
    if (validate == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "ValidateInterceptor installed on non-@Validate method");
    }
    for (Class<? extends RequestValidator> validatorClass : validate.value()) {
      RequestValidator validator = validatorClass.newInstance();
      validator.validate((HttpServletRequest) invocation.getArguments()[0]);
    }
    return invocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Jeff, it works as expected! Sorry I don't have 15 reputation because this is my first post here, So I could not Vote up for you answer. Very appreciated.

Comment: @user1960799 Glad to help! If my answer was the most helpful, please use [the checkbox under the arrows](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to mark mine as the "Accepted Answer". It's even better than an upvote. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: If you can manage to use injector.getInstance(validatorClass) instead of validatorClass.newInstance() you could even use DI inside your Validators ...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it this way? Why not create two annotations?

I don't believe you can do directly, but you could write a `MethodInterceptor` that executed the `MethodInterceptor`s in the methods annotation. But again, why?

Comment: Hi mlk, thanks for your answer. Yes, I did this by define separate annotation in the past. But I found I have to define too many annotations. For this case, I have to define 4 since some methods just use one interceptor, but some use both with different order.
1. OneInterceptor.class
2. TwoInterceptor.class
3. {OneInterceptor.class,TwoInterceptor.class}
4. {TwoInterceptor.class, OneInterceptor.class}